# Differences between "just might" and "might just?"

Tags: word-order, adverb-position, focusing-adverbs

Can someone help me understand more precisely the connotative differences between "just might" and "might just

I came upon this dilemma while working on a short comic strip. In the first panel, a person is attempting an unorthodox approach to a problem, saying:

> It might just work.

The second panel, moments later:

> It didn't work.

I'm unsure if the effect would be significantly altered if the words were swapped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"might just work"` sounds like "it might simply work--that is, without the complications one might predict."

`"just might work"` has a blossoming optimism. It suggests that something that you'd think wouldn't work actually has a decent shot at working.

Comment: Macmillan: We might just get there in time if we hurry. ( this seems to show the exact opposite)

Comment: Could it be that the first one also contains a notion of surprise? That, if you say your example, you just realized that it (simply) works, and that this fact is surprising to you? So that, if someone commands: `do xy`, to communicate that you don't actually take commands, but will do xy anyway, on your own accord, answer `I might just do that`. ?

Answer (score 2):

`"It might just work"` more sounds like positive and pragmatic
Eg: You are working on a research and you finally say " It might just work" seems like you are hopeful & have some sort of surety

`"It just might work"` sound more as a natural occurrence & skeptic.
Eg: You are stuck with your car left not working you say "it might just work" a little less hopeful plus relying on luck to work it out for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think `It might just work` could also suggest the meaning `"It might work, but barely"`. With the annotation that the purpose will probably be fulfilled, but only that and nothing more.

Comment: *I think "it might just work" could also suggest the meaning "It might work, but barely"... but only that and nothing more.* In general, they are interchangeable. For example, I just wrote an email to my favorite baseball-themed podcast, which is coming to an end soon, thanking them for a great season. I also told them "I might just listen to [your] football podcast" despite not really following football. I could just have easily gone with "I just might listen". They feel the same to me. I think those that are trying to separate them are just expressing how the phrases feel to them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it's much simpler than all that. To illustrate, I'll address (A) "We might just make it" versus (B) "We just might make it" (for instance, to our destination, given a low tank of gas).

(A)  "I think we'll make it . . . but barely."

(B) "Being more optimistic than I normally am, I think there's a chance we'll get there."

A similar bugaboo is (A) "just can't" versus (B) "can't just":

"You just can't do that!" ("Doing that is categorically wrong.  Unacceptable.  I/we won't stand for it.")

"You can't just [   ]" (sit there; show up; vote; adjust the yaw, but not the roll and pitch.)  More is required; what you've done is incomplete, lazy, half-assed.

Answer (score -1):

We just might have to use both phrases in different sentences; we might just find a clearer—or better—answer.

X: I have already done everything to make my Internet connection faster.
Y: You just might have to turn off your router to fix the problem.

X: What are you doing tonight after your shift?
Y: I might just drop by my parents' house.

X: Are you attending Mia's wedding next month?
Y: I'm not sure yet. I might just go to the reception.

X: It would be more fun if you meet us at the mall, do some window-shopping, and check out the theatre.
Y: Hmmm. I'm not making promises. I just might turn up.

X: I wish I could see ghosts.
Y: Be careful what you wish for. You just might get it.

Comment: Can you explain the difference more clearly? If the asker is confused about the use, more examples without explanation probably won't help.

Comment: In my sample sentences, "might just" suggests considering a deed from a list of options (I might just show up at the mall, but I probably won't go shopping nor see a movie), whereas "just might" implies performing an action that is deemed not likely to work but might work: the act could be a result of a stroke of luck, or it could be a possible but unknown—or not tried and tested—solution to a problem (the mere shutting off and on of the router could possibly do the trick).